# emacs --eval '(ediff "$1" "$2")' how to put this line in to shell-script?

Tags: bash, shell, emacs

I want to put the following line:

```
emacs --eval '(ediff "$1" "$2")'
```

into a shell script, so I dont need to write this long and complicated line everytime. However, when I put it into my shell script as it is, I get an error:

```
ediff-find-file: File `$1' does not exist or is not readable
```

I guess there is some sort of `"` escaping problem here and I need to put some `\` in this line. What exactly do I need to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is normal, your string is surrounded with single quotes, and variables are not expanded within single quotes.

You should use double quotes so that they get expanded, and escape existing double quotes in the string:

```
emacs --eval "(ediff \"$1\" \"$2\")"
```

It is worth noting that when expanding variables, *only the outer quotes matter*. That is:

```
$ A=foo
$ echo "'$A'"
```

will print `'foo'`. The fact that single quotes surround `$A` here does not matter: the outer quotes are double quotes.

Answer (score 6):

Your immediate problem is that the single quotes prevent all expansion by the shell. You need double quotes for any kind of expansion to happen. However, you can't just write `emacs --eval "(ediff \"$1\" \"$2\")"` because the file names would not be properly quotes for Emacs, so your script would break if the file names contained `"` or `\`.

Fortunately, there's a very simple solution:

```
emacs --eval '(ediff command-line-args-left)' "$@"
```

It would be better to reuse an existing Emacs process if there is one, by calling `emacsclient`. Unfortunately, with Emacsclient, `--eval` treats all its arguments as Lisp expressions. So you need to do the quoting inside the shell. In bash or ksh, you can use `${VARIABLE//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` to add backslashes before the double quotes and backslashes; it's a little painful but it works.

```
quoted1=${1//\\/\\\\}; quoted1=${quoted1//\"/\\\"}
quoted2=${2//\\/\\\\}; quoted2=${quoted2//\"/\\\"}
emacsclient -a '' --eval "(ediff \"$quoted1\" \"$quoted2\")"
```

Comment: For a reason I do not know, I need to replace the file by its absolute path in order for ediff to read them. I added 
    file1=$(readlink -f $1)
    file2=$(readlink -f $2)
and ediff load $file1 and $file2

Answer (score 1):

To have an easy function called "ediff" in my `$HOME/.profile` I combined two tips together. The one from [Gilles above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848819/emacs-eval-ediff-1-2-how-to-put-this-line-in-to-shell-script/8855989#8855989) and from the [defunitive blog](https://defunitive.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/invoking-emacs-ediff-from-the-command-line/). I added the `-c` argument for emacsclient and emacs as the fallback editor:

```
ediff () {
    if [ "X${2}" = "X" ]
    then
        echo "USAGE: ediff <FILE 1> <FILE 2>"
    else
        quoted1=${1//\\/\\\\};quoted1=${quoted1//\"/\\\"}
        quoted2=${2//\\/\\\\};quoted2=${quoted2//\"/\\\"}
        emacsclient -c -a emacs -e "(ediff \"$quoted1\" \"$quoted2\")"
    fi
}
```